# Ext.Combobox remove "loading" text (ext-4.0.2a)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

how can i remove "loading.." text when i type a letter into remote ComboBox??

in extjs 3.3.1 i've used:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox,
  { onBeforeLoad:
     function() {this.selectedIndex = -1;}
});
```

but now i see that not work!

how can i do?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `loadingText: ''` in your config.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable the loading mask on the BoundListView not on the ComboBox itself. Pass listConfig options to the list view with your combobox:

```
listConfig: {
     loadMask: false
}
```